# Sqlite : duplicate column name:

Tags: sqlite

While selecting some data from a sqlite db using the cli:

```
SELECT * FROM 'myData' WHERE (StateCode != 'NULL' AND IHV != 'NULL');
```

I got:

```
[1:36:30 PM][vscode-sqlite][ERROR] duplicate column name: LHV
```

checking the schema:

```
sqlite> .open test.db
sqlite> .schema myData

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "myData" (id integer primary key autoincrement,  PropertyId text UNIQUE, Year text, PropertyType text, PropertyTypeCode text, InCart text, Status text, HideValues text, MapAddress text, AppraisedValueDisplay text, DetailUrl text, PaymentProcessor text, StateCode text, IHV text, LHV text );
sqlite>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: create a new table, copy data into the new table and delete your old table.

Comment: Please provide a MRE as described in the wiki  for the tag you used: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I have a strange feeling that there is a lookalike typo involved, the two table names which are very different in caps get very similar in mixed case "lhv" (lower case L)  and "Ihv" (upper case i). Please confirm that this is not part of your problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch , how do I confirm this?

Comment: You can read all occurrences of "IHV", "LHV" and their mixed case occurrences in your code and think "Do I really mean that one at that code part?" You can  replace all of them by caps version. You can make a MRE according to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info You can force yourself to think systematically by changing the MRE to using a clearly different name.

Comment: By the way, in order to prevent the bounty from being lost by not being awardable, you should increase chances for an answer by using the hints in [ask]. Making a MRE is an important part of that and might simply solve the problem for you right away.

Comment: @user1592380 Does using `"mydata'` instead of `'mydata'` and/or `IS NOT NULL` change anything:
`SELECT * FROM "myData" WHERE (StateCode IS NOT NULL AND IHV IS NOT NULL);`?